# How do I close One table row while clicking on another

Tags: vue.js

I'm fetching data into the table and on clicking any table row it open a nested colspan inside table row.
I want to close previous table row if i click on another table row (Like accordion does )

This is my Vue File

{{index+1}}
                  
                    {{statement.paper_quality_id.paper_quality}} -
                    {{statement.paper_size_id.length}} X {{statement.paper_size_id.width}} -
                    {{statement.paper_brand_id.paper_brand}} -
                    {{statement.thickness}}

> {{Math.ceil((statement.in_total_before - statement.total_out_before)/500)}}

```
              <td>
                <div class="row">
                  <div
                    class="col-md-4 text-center"
                  >{{Math.floor((statement.total_sheets_in_range)/500)}}</div>
                  <div
                    class="col-md-4 text-center"
                  >{{Math.floor((statement.total_sheets_in_range)%500)}}</div>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div class="row">
                  <div
                    class="col-md-4 text-center"
                  >{{Math.floor((statement.total_outward_range)/500)}}</div>
                  <div
                    class="col-md-4 text-center"
                  >{{Math.floor((statement.total_outward_range)%500)}}</div>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    {{
                    Math.floor((((statement.in_total_before - statement.total_out_before) + (statement.total_sheets_in_range)) - statement.total_outward_range)/500)
                    }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    {{
                    Math.floor((((statement.in_total_before - statement.total_out_before) + (statement.total_sheets_in_range)) - statement.total_outward_range)%500)
                    }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr :id="'show_'+index" style="display : none">
              <td colspan="6">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Opening</th>
                    <th>Inward</th>
                    <th>Outward</th>
                    <th>Balance</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr v-for="(_statement,index) in statements_details">
                    <td>{{_statement.date}}</td>

                    <td>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.opening.total_in - _statement.opening.total_out)/500)}}</div>
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.opening.total_in - _statement.opening.total_out)%500)}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">{{Math.ceil((_statement.inward)/500)}}</div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">{{Math.ceil((_statement.inward)%500)}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.outward)/500)}}</div>
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.outward)%500)}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.outward)/500)}}</div>
                        <div
                          class="col-md-3 text-center"
                        >{{Math.ceil((_statement.outward)%500)}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

This is my js file

PostLedgerID(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

```
  const AccountDetail = {
    id: this.id,
    start_date: this.start_date + ' 00:00:00.957761',
    end_date: this.end_date + ' 00:00:00.957761'
  }
  var vm = this;
  axios.post('/Statement/', AccountDetail)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      vm.statements = response.data;

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
},

//Show Hide Nested Table
statementDetail(rowid, paper_id, brand_id, size_id, thickness) {

  const userDetail = {
    account_access_key_id: $('#ledger_id').val(),
    start_date: this.start_date + ' 00:00:00.957761',
    end_date: this.end_date + ' 00:00:00.957761',
    paper_quality_id: paper_id,
    paper_brand_id: brand_id,
    paper_size_id: size_id,
    thickness: thickness
  }
  axios.post('/StatementDetail/', userDetail)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(userDetail)
      $('#show_' + rowid).toggle();


      this.statements_details = response.data;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is your `@click` event? You can pass index of item and save to `data()` and open only row with that index. @monish

Comment: <tr @click="statementDetail(index,statement.paper_quality_id.id,statement.paper_brand_id.id,statement.paper_size_id.id,statement.thickness)">

Comment: Can you provide your data and update your question?